# Deploying from WebMatrix for AppHarbor

Tags: deployment, web-config, webmatrix, appharbor

I am trying to deploy to AppHarbor a website. Of course, i had to disable precompilation and other stuff, but appharbor builds it fine and deploys it to http://nitelists.apphb.com/.

However if you enter, you see a forbiden acess error, don't know why. 
(note that i am using the SQL lite database that comes integrated with WebMatrix)

Do i have to change something of the web.config file to make it work? This are the actual file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration > 

</configuration>
```

Comment: Because I have to ask - why not https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/ :-)

Comment: Also - could you please the exact error you're getting?

Comment: It looks like your app is generating a standard YSOD. You can inspect application errors in the [AppHarbor interface](http://blog.appharbor.com/2011/03/28/application-errors) and find more debugging suggestions in the FAQ: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My web.config file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```